# +2 pts refund from a retracted downvote is cap-exempt

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, down-votes, daily-reputation-limit

I think this is what happened:

- I reached my cap
- Someone downvoted (so now -2 from cap)
- Someone else upvoted (only get +2 instead of +10, cap reached again)
- Downvote retracted (+2 refunded, now +2 above cap)

Everything's fine according to the audit, though (https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), so maybe this is a known bug that isn't worth fixing.

*Note*: by "fine" I mean that I do not actually have the +2 pts above cap according to the audit.

Comment: I think it's not worth fixing, how many reputation points can you squeeze with this feabug?

Comment: @Downvoter: and like I said, the audit caps the refund properly, so a simple recalc would fix the number anyway. I'm just reporting what I found, that's all. Not complaining about anything.

Comment: Didn't take it like that, just offering my opinion

Comment: @Downvoter @polygene Don't worry. You both have valid points. :)

Comment: @JuanManuel: How many? Well, how many sock puppets do you want? It would be interesting to gain extra rep through *downvoting* yourself (and reversing it quickly).

Answer (score 4):

In a build rolling out right now, this bug will finally be fixed.  Reversals of downvotes will restore the amount of rep they should.  For example, if you had the following rep *for categories that apply to the reputation cap*, the results would be:

- 198 rep **+2** rep = 200
- 199 rep **+1** rep = 200
- 200 rep **+0** rep = 200

In short, downvote reversals will *finally* respect the reputation cap.