# Earning reputation by downvoting?

Tags: bug, reputation, down-votes, hot-questions, daily-reputation-limit

I found a way to earn reputation by downvoting. Specifically: If I downvote a post, then wait a while, then un-downvote the post, my net reputation count increases by 1.

Here's why it's happening. Two days ago, I posted an answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2345327/is-being-a-right-triangle-both-necessary-and-sufficient-for-the-pythagorean-theo) question on math.SE. It became a "hot" network question and I quickly reached my daily reputation limit. Thus, the question kept getting upvoted, but I wasn't earning reputation for it (as it should be).

Today, I once again reached my daily reputation limit. After reaching this limit, I downvoted a post on math.SE. So, my daily earned reputation was effectively 199. The next time somebody upvoted my question, I gained +1 reputation. **But then, I retracted the downvote.** To my surprise, I gained another +1 reputation.

Here is the data on the reputation I gained today:

[image]

Usually, I would have earned 215 in total: 200 reputation from upvotes and 15 from one accepted answer. But instead I earned 216 because I gained the extra +1 from retracting the downvote after already being "reimbursed".

Obviously, this trick isn't widely applicable. A user has to already have reached their reputation cap. And due to the limit of 40 votes per day, they would only be able to use this trick to earn a maximum of 40 bonus reputation points per day. I realize I'm not the first to point out inconsistencies in the voting system (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48116/2-pts-refund-from-a-retracted-downvote-is-cap-exempt), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2241/daily-reputation-cap-effectively-counts-downvotes-twice), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/504/why-is-the-inconsistent-reputation-system-by-design?noredirect=1&lq=1)). But as far as I can tell, this is the first instance where it is possible for a user to reliably game the system to earn 40 reputation per day without making any contributions.

Is this a bug? Should it be addressed?

Comment: I bet you that your reputation will be corrected overnight and you'll lose these points you never had.

Comment: You actually can't earn rep by downvoting. If you dowvoted an answer, that was deleted, you'll regain your rep, you lost for downvoting that answer.

Comment: **`[status-bydesign]`**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The system already corrects this on its own. We don't run a recalc on your account every time you change a vote - that's just way too expensive. Instead, whenever your account gets recalculated again next, you'll lose the 1 reputation because it won't make sense anymore. You'll only keep the erroneous reputation as long as it takes the system to schedule a recalc for you.